# Rollupjs + bson lib

Tags: javascript, bson, rollup

Im working with project that is written in Node CommonJS modules. My point was to make this project accessible from a browser. I decided to use Rollup.js, so when the bundle is created you can include script in browser and use functions from library (thanks to iife format). I needed to install plugins for Rollup to convert CommonJS modules into ES6 modules, so browser can understand it.

Everything is fine, except that this project uses bson library from npm. This bson library is required in one of my modules which uses some of it's functions. After I create a bundle and include it into index.html an error appears in console which says: "require is not defined". When I look inside the created bundle there are some requires.

```
var Map = require('./map'),
  Long = require('./long'),
  Double = require('./double'),
  Timestamp = require('./timestamp'),
  ObjectID = require('./objectid'),
  BSONRegExp = require('./regexp'),
  Symbol$1 = require('./symbol'),
  Int32 = require('./int_32'),
  Code = require('./code'),
  Decimal128 = require('./decimal128'),
  MinKey = require('./min_key'),
  MaxKey = require('./max_key'),
  DBRef = require('./db_ref'),
  Binary = require('./binary');
```

I have created simple code in Plunker to illustrate you my config and simplified structure.
https://plnkr.co/edit/YuiVJxhwhjUQ0Flw0Mg3?p=preview

In this plunker there are two simple modules, which one requires bson library, and second requires this first module. There is also Rollup config file, where I use plugins (if there is no globals plugin there is an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`).

I'm really confused. Am I misunderstanding something? Why isn't it converted into ES6 modules just like other of my code?

Here is link to bson library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

In order for rollup to bundle your application you need  to transform commonjs modules into es modules first, this is done with rollup-plugin-commonjs (https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) which you are already using, maybe you could explicitly set in the options to include the bson package. I usually use it like this, just in case:

`commonjs({
  include: ['node_modules/**']
})`

If some library uses node global modules you will need to include them in the browser, thats why you need rollup-plugin-node-globals.

Finally, if you take a look at bson github repository there is a folder called browser_build, which contains the UMD definition of the library, so if you require 'bson/browser_build' instead of 'bson' it should work, and you may not need to use globals plugin.

Take a look at js module formats (cjs, umd, iife, es, amd) it is worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I no longer work on this project, but maybe it will help someone else.